# Select all rows with date column equal to today's date in postgres to the minute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I essentially want to run a query like:

SELECT * FROM t where date={time right now to the minute}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date_trunc()` for your exact question:

```
where date = date_trunc('minute', now())
```

However, I suspect you really want the span of one minute:

```
where date >= date_trunc('minute', now()) and
      date < date_trunc('minute', now()) + interval '1 minute'
```